# Is the cantonese expression 五福臨門 present in Mandarin too?

Tags: mandarin, expressions, cantonese

A recent question prompted me to look for expressions related to the Chinese New Year and, among them, I found one that particularly stroke me as interesting:

> 五福臨門  = according to the poster it means: *"five happinesses bestowed on your household"*
>
> <sup>Source: [Chinese New Year phrases](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/phorum/read.php?1,77140,77140), third post by "14k Guy", 7<sup>th</sup> expression listed.</sup>

I suppose that the pronunciation provided is Cantonese, since the site seems to be related to Cantonese.

Anyway, looking up the expression as a whole doesn't give any results in Mandarin, apparently, whereas looking up each character alone, the meaning seems to match... So I wonder, does this expression exist in current Mandarin as well? If not, is there an equivalent?

In both cases, I'd like to know why "five happenesses", is it related to the [number meanings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_in_Chinese_culture#Five) in Chinese culture?

Comment: It exists in both Cantonese and Mandarin.

Answer (score 7):

Of course it exists in Mandarin. I didn't know it is a Cantonese expression. Maybe it should be just "Chinese expression".

I cannot answer whether the meaning are the same. I don't know Cantonese. But I think the meaning should be the same in Cantonese and Mandarin.

"五福" comes form [《尚书·洪范》](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikisource/zh/w/index.php?title=%E5%B0%9A%E6%9B%B8/%E6%B4%AA%E7%AF%84&variant=zh-hans):

> 五福：一曰寿，二曰富，三曰康宁，四曰攸(yōu)好(hào)德，五曰考终命。

which are long life, being rich, being healthy, clement, having a peaceful end (death). It may or may not be related to the number meaning of five, I don't know. Maybe the original author picked five because five is a good number.

And currently, most Chinese cannot list what "五福" are, though "五福临门" is commonly used.

Comment: Oh, then it's weird I didn't find it... What about that "five"?

Comment: @Alenanno, I have to look up what "五福" are.

Comment: I can't list the "five" until I read the source. By the way, it seems the link is blocked. I can't browse it.

Comment: @Huang The link is from wikisource.

Comment: @fefe I really can't browse it. I guess it's blocked by something.Anyway, thanks. I am sure to find and read the source.

Comment: I don't think this term is common in Mandarin. It's more common in Cantonese.